# Updating two objects in the same transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have a two classes defined as follows:

```
public class CallDetail {

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "callDetail", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Task> tasks = new HashSet<Task>();

}

public class Task {

    @ManyToOne
    private CallDetail callDetail;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Task> preRequisiteTask = new HashSet<Task>();
}
```

I have two objects of class CallDetail which are already in database. I then attempt the following update in the service layer:

```
Task countStock = new Task();
Task takeOrder = new Task();
takeOrder.getPreRequisites().add(countStock);

callOne.getTaskInstances.add(countStock);
callTwo.getTaskInstances.add(taskOrder);

try {
        callDetailService.updateCallDetail(callOne);
        isValid = true;
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
if (isValid) {
            callDetailService.updateCallDetail(callDetail);
        }
```

When the update runs, the error I get is:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: za.co.itdynamics.ccs.domain.Task
```

How do I prevent this error from happening when both CallDetail objects are related to each other (where takeOrder in callOne has a prerequisite of countStock in callTwo)? Is it possible to update both CallDetail objects (callOne and callTwo) in one transaction?

Answer (score 2):

Add cascade for the `preRequisiteTask`:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Task> preRequisiteTask = new HashSet<Task>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course you have to start a transaction at the beginning (`@Transactional`)

Then you need to persist both Tasks. There are at least two ways:

- add `CascadeType.PERSIST` (or `.ALL`) to the `@OneToMany` relationship, or
- invoke `EntityManager.persist(countStock)` and `EntityManager.persist(takeOrder)` **BEFORE** you add them to an already persisited entity.

*(I prefer the second way.)*